# How to get the class list of one element to another element

Tags: angular

I have an input field, if the input is visited then I am adding a class to its list, and I have a  element, when the class list of input contains visited I need to display span element

I tried in component it is working, but I want to know if I can achieve this only on HTML ?

```
<input #cardHolder placeholder="Cardholder name"  id="card-holder-name"
       [(ngModel)]="accountHolderName"
       [class.error]="!validateAccountHolder()"
       (blur)="cardHolder.classList.add('visited')" aria-label="cardholder name">
```

In the component I have function `validateAccountHolder()` which checks the length

```
<span *ngIf="validateAccountHolder() && cardHolder.classList.contains('visited')"></span>
```

I expect to show span element when there is class visited for input element.
Or please let me know what is the easiest solution without heavy logic in component file

Comment: There are no issues when accessing the classList property with a template variable https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fa9dge?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get all of the class of the input

```
var classList = document.getElementById('inputID').className.split(/\s+/);
for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
    if (classList[i] === 'yourclass ') {
        //do whatever you want
    }
}
```

I hope this helps  you